# Where to ask for studies about companies developers' investment?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I would like to investigate about the time and amount of money needed by a company to develop products or services like Facebook, Stack Overflow, ReSharper, MyFitnessPal, Todoist or similar.

Which site of the network could fit a question like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it's not really a good question because *it depends*.

There's matters of scale (it's very different running a site for 1 user, 10 users 100 users, or several million users). It also is a matter of working out what sort of performance characteristics, what sort of corporate and development environment....

After close to a decade - SE's still *in development* in many ways. The workforce and what it comprises of changes over time.

It's roughly like asking "how long is a piece of string?"

It's also worth remembering many of these *start* as pet projects - and grow organically, and you could easily *start* as a lone coder with a AWS instance and grow big. SO was probably less than a dozen people to start with, and the composition of the workforce has probably changed with business goals.

There's no real good fit because the question is pretty broad.